# Cant copy xml file to another project

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

Im trying to use xml file in a new project.
I just copied and pasted the xml file in a new xml file in my new project and when I try to pick up this xml layout by setContentView it won't let me pick up this layout but all other are available...

Comment: you need to copy the xml into the layout folder.  Not into an xml.  Eclipse support copy and pasting of xml files

Comment: Can you see the xml file under the `res/layout` folder in your package explorer?

Comment: Pramod - I just pasted it at the layout folder and still no pick up choice... Martin - Yes the xml file is there

Comment: please upload a picture of your job

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this in my environment, but have seen similar problems in the past.

Try the following:

1. Make sure you have no error markers in your project.
2. Do a clean build of your android project.
3. Restart Eclipse.
4. Delete your "gen" directory and wait for it to be recreated.

Comment: The issue was the drawable folder, I had a photo with an uppercut F and thats made problems with the R.java file.

Comment: Aww.. Those kinds of problems make my blood boil.  Would be nice to get a meaningful error, wouldn't it? :)  Glad you solved your problem.